# Newly built pc won’t boot

Tags: boot, desktop-computer

I’ve recently built a new pc. Here are the parts: Zotac GTX 770 OC 2, Gigabyte B75M - D3H, Dell Hynix 16GB(2x8) 1333mhz, intel i5 3570s, Raidmax 500w 80 plus Bronze PS. I turned it on and the fans light up and spin including the gpu fan but it won’t boot. It makes this continuous beeping noise. No change in sight pitch or anything. The bios is AMI. Does anyone have a guess on what’s wrong with my pc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this site is for answering focused questions, not for guessing

Comment: what do you mean by `continuous beeping noise`?

Comment: Standard question... did you take proper esd precautions? And no, momentarily touching metal occasionally does not count. If you did not, then you could have zapped just about anything and all.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be the most knowledgeable but I'll give it a go.

The beeping is most likely a diagnostic codes from your motherboard. After some scouring online, it seems like this is the POST/"beep" codes depending on your BIOS. For the AMI, it is:

1 short beep：Memory Error

2 short beeps：Memory parity check error.

3 short beeps：basic memory 64K address check error

4 short beeps：Real Time Clock malfunction .

5 short beeps：CPU error

6 short beeps：Keyboard error

7 short beeps：CPU interruption error

8 short beeps：Graphic card error

9 short beeps：Memory error

10 short beeps：CMOS error

11 short beeps：CPU cache memory malfunction

If that doesn't help, I'd try this **after**. For these steps, make sure your PC is turned off **AND** the plug is out.

1: Check that your connections inside the PC and outside (ex: the peripherals, power, etc.) are solid. If you aren't getting a display it may be your GPU specifically that is causing the problem.
1.5: Check that your RAM sticks are not properly seated/Reseat your RAM.

**Good luck!**